# matplotlib's contour algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib

I am trying to find out what kind of algorithm exactly matplotlib is using to find contours. After a little search, I found [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/pyplot-Extract-contourset-without-plotting-td15868.html#a15872) that the contour plot calls an underlying contour method written in C which, on a rectangle grid [-size,size]x[-size,size] with num_samp partitions per axis, boils down to something like:

```
import matplotlib._cntr as cntr
import numpy as np 

xgrid,ygrid = np.mgrid[-size:size:num_samp,size:size:num_samp]
zvals = func(xgrid, ygrid)
cont  = cntr.Cntr(xgrid, ygrid, zvals)     
nlist = cont.trace(level, level, 0)
return nlist[:len(nlist)//2]
```

to find a list of connected path components.
But I can't find any further information on those two methods, `Cntr` and `trace` even after trying to browse the github repository. I am particularly interested in the following questions:

- Under which condition does the algorithm throw away a point on the grid? Is it something as simple as comparing sign changes along the edges?
- Obviously there is some kind of interpolation happening (the resulting points are not necessarily points on the input grid), how exactly is this done and to which accuracy?

Any help welcome.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the source code where you found this. To me it seems matplotlib does not even use `._cntr` anymore.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the source as hyperlink. I use this momentarily with matplotlib 2.1.1 without problems

Comment: Seems that is 7 years old. In the meantime the algorithm has been ported from c to c++. [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/f66687c8cfa72bfe769ca79d60c00a453611543b/lib/matplotlib/contour.py#L1444) would be the entry point, pointing to [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/f66687c8cfa72bfe769ca79d60c00a453611543b/src/_contour.cpp#L596) c++ function.

Comment: Concerning the question, I do not understand what you mean by "throw away a point". I don't think anything is thrown away, but of course some cells on the grid are not relevant for certain levels. I think in general, the algorithm can be imagined like a snake wriggling from some start point along the level in question.

Comment: well the final list of points is smaller than the number of grid cells, so certainly some cells are "thrown away" as in "discarded because they are thought to not contain a section of the contour", that's what I mean. My assumption would be that they use some sort of marching squares algorithm, that would answer both my questions, but I can not verify that.